# Is there a way I can solve the module not found error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modulenotfounderror

I am creating a todo list web app but some and this error is occurring where it says

Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/Components/TodoList.js 6:0-57

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './react/cjs/react.development' in 'C:\Users\91826\Desktop\WD\projects\todo-list\src\Components'

Can someone please tell me how to solve this.

Code in TodoForm.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
export default function TodoForm(props){
  // state
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");


  const handleChange = e => {
    setInput(e.target.value)
    }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.addTask({
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000),
      text: input,
      isComplete: false
  })
    setInput('')
}
return(
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Add a todo" onChange={handleChange} className="todo-input" value={input} name="text"/>
      <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit} className= "todo-btn" >ADD TODO</button>
                                                 
</form>
);
}
```

Code in TodoList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from '.react/cjs/react.development';
 import TodoForm from './TodoForm'
export default function TodoList(){
   const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const addTask = task => {
    if (!task.text) {
      return
    }
     const newTodos = [task, ...todos];
    setTodos(newTodos);
}
  return <div>
     <TodoForm addTask={addTask} ></TodoForm>
   </div>;
}
```

Code in App.js

```
import './App.css';
import TodoList from './Components/TodoList'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="Todo-list-container">
     <TodoList/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You're using `import React, {useState} from "react";` correctly in one component. Why are you not using the same import in the file causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

`useState` should be imported from React itself, so these 2 lines:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from './react/cjs/react.development';
```

Should be changed to

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
```